# Can I get the last value from an iterator?

Tags: lua

I would like to split a string by a separator and get only the last part. I
don't care about the rest. I know I can do:

```
local last
for p in string.gmatch('file_name_test', '_%w+$') do last = p end
```

Which works, but is, IMHO, ugly.

Is there a more elegant way to say:

```
local last = string.gmatch('file_name_test', '_%w+$')[1]
```

Which doesn't work because `gmatch` returns an iterator (and not a table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the other answers do give you a correct answer for your *situation*, I am going to propose an answer to your *question*. Which was to get the first item from an iterator.

And the answer is actually quite simple. Since an iterator is just something that continues to return until it returns nil, we just have to call it!

```
local first = string.gmatch('file_name_test', '_%w+$')()
```

I am quite confused however, because in your question you also ask about the *last* thing it will return. I'm sad to say you cannot do this without iterating over them all, because an iterator cannot "jump ahead".

Answer (score 6):

Use `string.match` which is not an iterator:

```
local last = string.match('file_name_test', '_(%w+)$')
print (last)  --> test
```

Comment: Minor: Since the _ is considered a delimiter, it should not be part of the answer.  So, maybe this: local last = string.match('file_name_test', '_(%w+)$')

Comment: The question was a tiny bit unclear on that point, as the original code would also have returned the underscore. However I amended my answer to make the last word a capture, so now it just returns "test".

Answer (score 4):

The pattern `_%w+$` will only ever return a single match. That's because you anchored it at the end of the string, so it can only either match or fail to match (if there isn't an underscore followed by at least one %w character at the end).

The `g*` series of pattern matching are for iterating over a sequence of matches. If you want all the matches all at once (returned as multiple return values), use the non-`g`-prefixed functions. Like `string.match`:

```
string.match('file_name_test', '_%w+$')
```

If there is no match, then you'll get `nil` back.